# How to depict non-grid 3D data as heat map?

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, heatmap

I have 3 columns of numbers x, y, z, where x and y are coordinates and z is intencity. I would like to represent the data as heat map in gnuplot.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `dgrid3d` to fill in missing values:

```
set dgrid3d
splot 'input.txt' with pm3d
```